# Neo4j, reasonable content length of properties

Tags: neo4j

Sorry for my bad English.

I got pretty bad feeling about storing news articles in 'content' property of nodes. Is it ok?
If it is not ok, should i use child node for content or use mongodb for storing big chunks of data.

I am trying to create small community website, and just for fun i am using Neo4j. 
By 'big' i mean regular content of blogs\news sites ~ 10kb of html per post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only load those properties when you want to render a page it shouldn't pose a problem.

During traversals / queries you probably should not access those properties which will be lazily loaded.

Otherwise it is ok.

For instance the [CMS structr](http://structr.org) is build on Neo4j.